# Add items to dxCheckGroupBox1

Tags: delphi, devexpress

Maybe trivial but I cant seem to find where do you add items to dxCheckGroupBox1? I've scrolled through its settings but I just cant find where do you add items. Must be going blind ...
The only way I could do it is by dropping manually a check box inside.

Comment: I have no Delphi around right now, but with DX controls the relevant stuff often is inside the `Properties` property. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a group (like `TPanel`) but with checkbox (left-top corner). 
You can add any components (edits/memos/etc) to this group in normal way, for example drag and drop from palette or CTRL+DOT and find by name, ...

If you need set of checkboxes, then you can use `TcxCheckListBox` instead, seems it is what you need actually. And for `TcxCheckListBox` you can use property `Items` (checkboxes only of course) to edit items.

Comment: It figures... no wonder I could not find anything in the properties. But, I never used this before so I thought I'd ask first....Thank you.